# Filter a list with several elements in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I try to write a predicat filter/3

example `filter([a,a,b,c,d,d],[a,d],L)` and L unify with [b,c]

i already write a delete/3 predicat, and i use that for my filter

```
delete([],_,[]).
delete([A|X],E,Z) :- A==E, delete(X,E,Z).
delete([A|X],E,[A|Z]) :- A \== E, delete(X,E,Z).

filter(M,[],M).                                                                                                                                                                                             
filter([K|M],[E|N],Z) :- delete([K|M],E,Z), filter(Z,N,B).
```

Delete work well, but filter not, a example with trace

`filtre([1,1,3,7,7],[1,7],Z).`

tree last line of the trace are :

`N-3 Call: (10) filtre([3], [], _18304470) ? creep
   N-2 Exit: (10) filtre([3], [], [3]) ? creep
   N-1 Exit: (9) filtre([3, 7, 7], [7], [3]) ? creep
   N   Exit: (8) filtre([1, 1, 3, 7, 7], [1, 7], [3, 7, 7]) ? creep`

Line N-3 and N-2 i see prolog found right result, but he return [3,7,7] instead of [3] and i dont understand why he dont stop at line N-2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code, the first thing you obtain is `Singleton variables: [B]`. Usually singleton variables indicate an error in the logic because those variables are never used. In this case, the program does not return the correct result because first you should call `delete([K|M],E,Z1)` on a list `Z1`, then call filter again in this way `filter(Z1,N,Z).`

Comment: Thanks for help, but i dont really understand why its working .. i dont really understand logic behind prolog, how each portion of my predicat would be executed

Comment: @MasterAI you have accepted this answer, which means you consider it a sufficient response to your question.